# TypeError: data.tostring is not a function at Object.<anonymous>

Tags: node.js

I was trying to execute this code:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var data = fs.readFileSync("text.txt");
console.log(data.tostring());
console.log("End Here");
```

And the below thing was on my output screen:

```
C:\Users\SURYA TEJA\Desktop\Node JS\node examples\blocking.js:3
console.log(data.tostring());
                 ^

TypeError: data.tostring is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SURYA TEJA\Desktop\Node JS\node examples\blocking.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)    
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:122
0:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)        
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)

    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run
_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the example [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-readfilesync-method/) instead which handles the encoding so you don't need to run the toString() in this case:

```
// Node.js program to demonstrate the 
// fs.readFileSync() method 

// Include fs module 
const fs = require('fs'); 

// Callling the fs.readFile() method 
// for reading file 'input1.txt' 
fs.readFile('./input1.txt', 
        {encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'}, 
        function(err, data) { 
    if(err) 
        console.log(err); 
    else
        console.log(data); 
}); 

// Calling the fs.readFileSync() method 
// for reading file 'input2.txt' 
const data = fs.readFileSync('./input2.txt', 
            {encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'}); 

// Display data 
console.log(data);
```

You can also add a check like `if(data) console.log(data.toString();`

Answer (score 0):

It's not data.tostring(), it's data.toString(); with capital 'S'.